# animate bootstrap cards replacing disappearing ones

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Imagine a website that makes use of [bootstrap cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns).

Now, if you were to click on a button so that the some of the upper cards disappeared, the cards underneath will just magically fill the place of the recently disappeared cards in a blink of an eye. **How can the cards underneath the disappearing cards smoothly transition up and take their place?**

**NOTE: the answer I am looking for just have to solve my problem - I don't care how.**

---

I have tried the following:

```
#projects.card { //expect that each card have been supplied with the class name 'card'
    -moz-transition: 2s;
    -ms-transition: 2s;
    -o-transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

---

A gif that showcases the transitioning not taking place:
[Click here to view the GIF](https://gyazo.com/6832216f6020945d5c3f363afb23cf4f)

Comment: You can't, you'd need to change the styling/move the cards on the lower part. Transition is a property that controls the transition from one style to another style. You can't hide a completely different element, all that's doing is rearranging the visual elements based on the changes, not changing the styling.

Comment: @TheJSWizard What would you advice me to do to obtain my goal?

Comment: How do they disappear? Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @KoshVery By setting the `display: none;` property.

Comment: Well, so where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

very high level idea is to have all the positions in memeory and handle all the movement yourself based on those positions and change in position.

but you can use prebuilt libraries like https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that library! Is the cards used in the demo a part of the library? Or will I have to style the cards myself?

Comment: i am not sure but my guess , they should not be . You will have to style them yourself.